# OMP: How to find the right size of cache at runtime

Tags: c++, caching, parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following piece of (pseudo) code:

```
static void ConvertBuffer( unsigned char * buffer, const int width )
{
#pragma omp parallel for
  for ( int x = 0; x < width; ++x ) // one image row
    {
    RGB rgb = {0,0,0}; HSB hsb;
    rgb.red = (float)buffer[x] / 255.;
    RGBToHSB(rgb, hsb);
    buffer[x] = hsb.brightness * 255;
    }
}
```

This is a very naive implementation of an RGB → HSB conversion algorithm.

The first implementation would pull a single scanline (=one row of the image) at a time, in my case **65536 bytes**. However after trial and error on my particular system, I discovered that I could decrease the total computation time by a factor of **2**, if instead I would process **16** scanlines at a time (= 1048576 bytes).

What tool are available for me to guess that *magic number*, possibly at runtime so that I do not need to hard-code a magical value of 16 somewhere in my code ?

If I know that `RGBToHSB` is embarrassingly parallel and cache friendly, can I just completely fill the `L3 cache` and that should be close to the maximum possible speed ?

For reference, my system is described by:

```
$ sudo likwid-topology
-------------------------------------------------------------
CPU type:   Intel Core SandyBridge processor 
*************************************************************
Hardware Thread Topology
*************************************************************
Sockets:    1 
Cores per socket:   4 
Threads per core:   1 
-------------------------------------------------------------
HWThread    Thread      Core        Socket
0       0       0       0
1       0       1       0
2       0       2       0
3       0       3       0
-------------------------------------------------------------
Socket 0: ( 0 1 2 3 )
-------------------------------------------------------------

*************************************************************
Cache Topology
*************************************************************
Level:  1
Size:   32 kB
Cache groups:   ( 0 ) ( 1 ) ( 2 ) ( 3 )
-------------------------------------------------------------
Level:  2
Size:   256 kB
Cache groups:   ( 0 ) ( 1 ) ( 2 ) ( 3 )
-------------------------------------------------------------
Level:  3
Size:   6 MB
Cache groups:   ( 0 1 2 3 )
-------------------------------------------------------------

*************************************************************
NUMA Topology
*************************************************************
NUMA domains: 1 
-------------------------------------------------------------
Domain 0:
Processors:  0 1 2 3
Relative distance to nodes:  10
Memory: 122.332 MB free of total 5898.17 MB
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: @ElderBug that's my point. I am asking for 'how much', what's the proper size ?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood a bit what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really define a 'right size' for buffering. My answer would be to set it as big as reasonably possible. I would say somewhere between 10MB and 100MB, but you can set it higher if you can afford it, or lower if you are short on RAM.

If you are reading a file and writing to a file (same or another), you should consider using memory mapped files. This way you get rid of the buffering (managed by the OS), and you can call your function once for the whole image. Note that this is probably not a good idea on a 32-bit system if your image is bigger than 4GB.